# Camcorder and GPS together in App Inventor

Tags: app-inventor

I am trying to record the position of the device continuously while capturing video. But as soon as the camcorder is invoked the GPS freezes at that point and updates only after the video capture has been complete. Is there a way to solve the same.[image]

The aim is to record the track of the moving vehicle while capturing the video.
As soon as the video recording starts the Coordinates recorded in the file becomes stagnant and the last gets repeatedely stored in the file. The coordinates update only after the video recording is finished.

Comment: Please read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and add a screenshot of what you have tried. Thank you.

Comment: I have added a screenshot, hopefully this should convey what I am trying to do @Taifun

Comment: After the camcorder started, the camcorder is in the foreground and your app in the background... App Inventor apps usually can't run in the background... Do you get reasonable latitude/longitude values before starting the camcorder (not 0,0)? Did you set the clock timer always fires property to true?

Comment: @Taifun I have also tried clock always fire to true. But the result is the same. The coordinate freezes to last known point before starting camcorder. The Latitude/Longitude is not 0/0 before starting camcorder.                                    Is there any way to invoke camcorder in half screen so that app stays in the foreground and camcorder Also works at same time. Something like Routeshoot app in android

Answer (score 0):

Store the lat/long values in a list instead of using the `File` component like this

[image]

As you can see from the **Do it** result, it works fine 
Note: I did not enable bluetooth for the test, so therefore I got 0,0...